# Splitting a string in C into separate parts

Tags: c, string, compare

I've been trying to write a function in C that detects palindromes.  The program currently looks like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char palindrome[24]; int palength; int halflength;
    gets(palindrome);
    palength = strlen(palindrome);
    halflength = palength / 2;
    printf("That string is %u characters long.\r\n", palength);
    printf("Half of that is %u.\r\n", halflength);
    return 0;
}
```

Right now it detects the length of a string, and also shows what half of that is.  This is just to make sure it is working how I think it should be. What the rest of the function should do (if possible) is take the integer from "halflength" and use that to take that amount of characters off of the beginning and end of the string and store those in separate strings.  From there I'd be able to compare the characters in those, and be able return true or false if the string is indeed a palindrome.

TL;DR - Is it possible take a certain amount of characters (in this case the integer "halflength") off the front and end of a string and store them in separate variables.  Read above for more information on what I'm trying to do.

P.S. - I know not to use gets(), but didn't feel like writing a function to truncate \n off of fgets().

Comment: You don't need a separate copy of the string to detect palindromes.  Hint:  you iterate over the characters of a string using a pointer and you can iterate both forwards and backwards.

Comment: Why not just do this the classic way, which is to iterate from the beginning of the string to the halfway point, comparing with the corresponding character from the end?

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't think about that way of doing things.  Just wanted to do it for fun, and what I had started above was my first thought.

Comment: `substr` is what you are looking for... @James: Nice Hint ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int len = strlen(palindrome) - 1; // assuming no \n
int half = len << 1;
for (int i=0; i<=half; ++i)
  if(palindrome[i] != palindrome[len-i])
     return false;
return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you do something like this,

```
char *str1="lol",*str2;
str2=strrev(str1);
```

//if both are same then it actually is a palindrome ; )

Comment: -1 str1 and str2 must be char* not char, strrev is not C standard

Comment: why doesnt make one of his own strrev()?I never said use string.h ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Not sure what the chances of me making my own are though, haha.  Not exactly a C expert, pretty new, as in a week of C programming.

Comment: @Pardon:Just run a reverse loop and copy all the contents in a string and your done with a reversed string.

Answer (score 0):

Found out I was approaching the problem wrong.  How I should be doing this is iterating over the characters using a pointer both backwards and forwards.  Although if you'd still like to answer the original question it could still be useful at some point.